# SQL query to return rows whose column has a common value

Tags: sql-server, query

How can I query a *Microsoft SQL* table to return only the `InstNum` that has all `Profile` types `C` or `U`?

Please see my table structure below.

| InstNum | Profile |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | U |
| 001 | C |
| 001 | U |
| 002 | U |
| 002 | U |
| 002 | U |
| 003 | C |
| 003 | C |
| 003 | C |

I tried :

```
Select InstNum from Table Where Profile = 'C' Group By InstName;
```

But I received the results:

| InstNum |
| --- |
| 001 |
| 002 |
| 003 |

I was expecting to receive:

| InstNum |
| --- |
| 003 |

Because the `InstNum` of `0003` is the only one where all the `Profiles` are `C`.

What am I doing wrong? Does anybody have an idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Why not `002` ? Isn't your condition `return only an InstNum that has all Profile type 'C' or 'U'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an EXCEPT…

```
SELECT InstNum
FROM Table
WHERE Profile = 'C'

EXCEPT

SELECT InstNum
FROM Table
WHERE Profile <> ‘C'
GROUP BY InstNum;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH sameProfiles AS
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT([instNum]) cnt
      , [instNum]
    FROM
      (
        SELECT distinct
          [instNum]
          , [Profile]
        FROM
          myTable1 ) q
    GROUP BY
      [instNum]
    HAVING
      COUNT([instNum]) = 1)
SELECT DISTINCT
  [instnum]
FROM
  myTable1
WHERE
  [profile] = 'C'
and [instNum] in
  (
    SELECT
      [instNum]
    FROM
      sameProfiles);
```